# Hide tabs in React Native (createBottomTabNavigator)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am following the documentation of createBottomTabNavigator in React Native, in order to hide the bottom tabs. I have to add the navigationOptions and pass tabBarVisible: false.

Not sure what I am missing:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import AuthScreen from './screens/AuthScreen'
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen'
import MapScreen from './screens/MapScreen'
import DeckScreen from './screens/DeckScreen'
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen'
import ReviewScreen from './screens/ReviewScreen'
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
    Auth: AuthScreen,
    Main: {
      screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
        map: MapScreen,
        deck: DeckScreen,
        review: {
          screen: createStackNavigator({
            review: ReviewScreen,
            settings: SettingsScreen
          })
        }
      })
    }
  }, {
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarVisible: false,
      lazy: true
    }
  }
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `tabBarVisible` in `defaultNavigationOptions`, not `navigationOptions`:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
    Auth: AuthScreen,
    Main: {
      screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
        map: MapScreen,
        deck: DeckScreen,
        review: {
          screen: createStackNavigator({
            review: ReviewScreen,
            settings: SettingsScreen
          })
        }
      })
    }
  }, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      tabBarVisible: false
    },
    navigationOptions: {
      lazy: true
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: I am just curious, how did you know it? Because I checked the documentation, and they explain all the properties that you can change under "navigationOptions for screens inside of the navigator"